# How to convert a char array to a float array?

Tags: c++, types, casting, type-conversion

In order to train a classifier, it requires that the training data are specified using a set of float array. Unfortunately, the training data available to me are *byte arrays* (actually they are [Ipp8u](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/ipp/ipps/ipps_ch2/ch2_data_types.html) arrays, which can be converted to unsigned char arrays).

Essentially, given an unsigned char array, I need to convert it to a float array: in other words, given an unsigned char array, I should read it as a float array. Is this operation always allowed? Does the float data type allow all possible configurations of bits? If yes, how to implement this conversion?

Comment: I would make use of the stringstream library

Comment: Please clarify: is the data binary (and in correct byte order, etc), or human-readable strings?

Comment: @Chris: the data is binary (a byte sequence).

Comment: @enzom83: "binary" means nothing - what kind of binary format is it? Is it the binary representation of an array of your platform's `float`s? Or something else?

Comment: So each char should be interpreted as a byte with a value between 0 and 255?

Comment: @MatteoItalia: as I wrote in the question, the original array contains elements [`Ipp8u`](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/ipp/ipps/ipps_ch2/ch2_data_types.html) type.

Comment: If that's all there is to it, you made it seem more confusing than it is with things like "does the float data type allow all possible configurations of bits?"

Comment: Still not sure: If each unsigned char represents one value, the answer by @Dims works. If each 4 bytes are a binary float representation, things get a bit complicated.

Comment: I do not have to convert each element of the original array, but rather the entire array: I should convert each 4 bytes to a float value.

Comment: @enzom83 If you don't have to convert each element, what do you have to do? What are you not telling us?

Comment: A byte array is still a sequence of bits: given this sequence of bits, I should convert it to a float array. So, if the byte array contains 100 elements, then the float array should contain 25 elements.

Comment: @enzom83 are the `float` in this array [`Ipp32f`](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/ipp/ipps/ipps_ch2/ch2_data_types.html) values? (using the data type sheet your question links to, it seems appropriate, but thought I'd ask). The types in that link spell out pretty clearly what the endian-ness of the storage is, which is really the only missing link to answering your question.

Comment: @WhozCraig: the elements in the source array are `Ipp8u` values, but I need to read this `Ipp8u` array as a simple `float` array (because the classifier requires float data type).

Comment: Are you actually *using* the IPP framework SDK, or is this just a data blob you got from somewhere that happens to be a contiguous list of `Ipp32f` values in byte-form?

Comment: @WhozCraig: I'm using the IPP framework SDK.

Comment: See my answer below then, but i'll delete it if there is some reason you cannot use `ippsConvert_8u32f()` and walk your byte array 4-bytes at a time, stuffing results in your `Ipp32f` result array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the documentation of the [Intel Integrated Performance Primitives](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/ipp/ipps/), the function:

```
IppStatus ippsConvert_8u32f(const Ipp8u* pSrc, Ipp32f* pDst, int len);
```

would seem a most-handy function for doing **exactly** what you're looking for.

Comment: Sounds like just what I need! Now I wonder if the `Ipp32f` type can be converted to the `float` type.

Comment: @enzom83 Hard to say. If Intel provides this as a direct conversion, or documents that one cant directly assign to a platform-*dependent* `float` from their SDK type of `Ipp32f`, that would be good and you're likely in the clear. As I see it, this is the only *documented* way of converting a `Ipp8u` byte stream converted from `Ipp32f` float(s) back into said-same. Chances are direct conversion from their `Ipp32f` to a system-`float` will work, but you should seriously check into supporting documentation about it.

Comment: I just read the fourth post on [this page](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/299355): `Ipp32f` is `float`.

Comment: @enzom83 If that is a viable source from Intel then you're likely in the clear. You would still need to do the conversion to an `Ipp32f` value, then assign the result to a system-`float` in your array. Don't just pass your array offset directly, as their function mandates *their* type. You just never know. I would continue looking for more concrete evidence of a platform-*independent* nature (i.e. Intel says you can freely interchange `Ipp32f` and `float` according to link "blah", but it definitely looks promising.

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to approximate real numbers. There are floating point representations where some bits represent an exponent and some other bits represent a coefficient, there are fixed point representations where some bits represent the whole number part and some bits represent the factional part, there are arbitrary finite precision representations where some number of 'digits' in some base are stored, etc., and for every general class of representation there is an infinite variety of details which would matter when converting that representation into `float`s.

Your question does not specify what representation the byte array contains. Specifying that the array is `Ipp8u` does not come close to providing the necessary information.

---

What you probably mean is that the byte array contains a byte representation of the machine's native representation of `float`s (which is probably IEEE-754), differing at most in endianess.

You can simply do a memcpy of data from the `char` array into an array of floats:

```
char c[10 * sizeof(float)] = {...};
float f[10];
std::memcpy(f, c, 10 * sizeof(float)); // or you can search for an implementation of bit_cast
```

One thing not to do is to simply cast the `char` array: `float *f = reinterpret_cast<float*>(c);` This cast probably has undefined behavior because `float` probably has stricter alignment requirements than `char`.

If the endianess differs then you go through the byte array first and reorder the bytes, something like this:

```
// assuming sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t)
for (int i; i<sizeof c; i+=sizeof(float)) {
    uint32_t i;
    std::memcpy(&i, c + i, sizeof(uint32_t));
    ntoh(i); // swaps bytes from Network TO Host order.
    std::memcpy(c + i, &i, sizeof(uint32_t));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do each operation explicitly, not relying on implicit conversion. First read array in the char form

```
unsigned char charArray[100];
// reading
```

then convert elements one by obe

```
float floatArray[100];
for(i=0; i<100; ++i) {
   floatArray[i] = (float) charArray[i];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, and you don't even need the `(float)`, unless you crank up your warning levels unrealistically high...

Comment: Yes but this is in favor of proclaimed explicitness.

Comment: I do not have to convert each element of the original array, but rather the entire array.

Comment: But the people here are not fond of that kind of typecasting in C++; they claim it belongs in C and you should use C++-specific typecasting in C++.

Answer (score -1):

You could just run an iterative conversion utilising [atof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/) in a for loop. Then you can just use the float array. I'm sure there is a one line solution though.